# Значение и происхождение слов станить, застанить

Tags: этимология, жаргон, неологизмы

Слова станить, застанить, стан из игровой среды. Каково значение и происхождение этих неологизмов?
Например, в выражениях: 
"Как станить в ПвП на 35 лейве?", 
"Станить самого себя.", 
"станит врага как минимум на 3 сек", 
"Пассивка Mark of the Storm позволяет станить врагов после трех последовательных умений.", 
"насчет стрел приврал, а вот чуча и свист станят вроде(1-2 раза был стан на парик со свиста и с чучи, возможно баг)".

Answer (score 1):

Из английского, как всегда в подобных случаях.

> Стан (англ. stun - “оглушать”) - временное оглушение врага с помощью заклинания, т.е. эффект от скилла, парализующий противника. В течение стана враг не может шевелиться.
>   Станить (англ. stun - “оглушать”) - оглушать врага с помощью заклинания.

http://freeonline.pp.ru/?p=762#r-016